# Set Title Bar of Window from Page

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I am trying to set the UI Element "AppBar" as my app's title bar. The UI Element is not inside my MainWindow.xaml and instead inside a page i have navigated to in MainWindow. This allows me to call click handlers on the AppBar (which is a WinUI3 CommandBar). "AppBar" is defined in the page's XAML. My Expectation is that any area of the CommandBar that is not a button will be able to be used to drag the window around.

What I've tried:
**Setting the titlebar from MainWindow:**

```
public MainWindow() 
{
   ...
   SomeClass myClass = new();
   SetTitleBar(myClass.AppBar);
   rootFrame.Content = myClass;
}
```

This visually results in what I want, but the buttons in my AppBar cannot be clicked.

**Setting the titlebar from SomeClass:**
I changed the App.xaml.cs to expose the window:

```
public partial class App : Application 
{
   public App()
   {
      this.InitializeComponent();
   }

   protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
   {
      m_window = new MainWindow();
      m_window.Activate();
   }

   public static Window Window { get { return m_window; } }
   private static Window m_window;
}
```

And in my class (not MainWindow):

```
public SomeClass() 
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   // AppBar is defined in SomeClass's XAML.
   App.Window.SetTitleBar(AppBar);
   ...
}
```

This throws the error

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

MyApp.App.Window.get returned null.
```

I got the idea for that from [this MS article on porting UWP to WinUI3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/guides/winui3#change-windowsuixamlwindowcurrent-to-appwindow)

Comment: It just means your SomeClass constructor is called too early and in fact, it's obvious since you construct SomeClass in MainWindow constructor so before the MainWindow reference is returned in OnLaunched. Chicken and egg problem. Why don't you just pass the Window to SomeClass constructor

Comment: @SimonMourier This works in theory! Thanks. Unfortunately, the buttons on the AppBar still cannot be interacted with. The whole thing can be used to drag the window. Is there a trick I'm missing? EDIT: This is intended behavior.

Comment: This is not theory, your code as is can be fixed easily passing Window in SomeClass constructor, so you should show some code that fully reproduce your problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier All good, I tried it and it works. When you set clickable elements as the title bar, you have to explicitly define the draggable regions of the UIElement. I didn't realize that when I asked my question.

Comment: @Robert could you give a working example? I have the same problem.